# How do I import a PyPI library to my bazel build

Tags: python, bazel

I'm new to Bazel and tyring to import a 3rd-party library from PyPI to try out a small build.

In the working directory, I have

1. an empty WORKSPACE file

2. a BUILD file with these two rules

```
py_binary(
    name = 'try_this_test',
    main = 'try_this_test.py',
    srcs = ['try_this_test.py'],
    deps = [
        ':test_cpu_usage',
    ]
)

py_library(
    name = 'test_cpu_usage',
    srcs = ['test_cpu_usage.py'],
    deps = [ "psutil"]
)
```

3. these two python files in the same directory

```
##### try_this_test.py #####
from test_cpu_usage import test_cpu_usage

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_cpu_usage()

##### test_cpu_usage.py #####
import os
import psutil

def test_cpu_usage():
    l1, l2, l3 = psutil.getloadavg()
    print(l1, l2, l3)
```

However, whenever I "bazel run", it gives me the following error.

```
in deps attribute of py_library rule //:test_cpu_usage: rule '//:psutil' does not exist
```

I tried solutions from few sites but still can't find a solution for myself.

1. https://github.com/horia141/bazel-pypi-package
2. https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python

Comment: Have a look at this example https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/tree/main/examples/pip_install